# Node.js Mocha unit testing not changing object value

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm using Mocha/Chai/Sinon to develop some unit tests on a Node.js application (Express). I made a fake request/response object to pass to the function that I'm trying to test. Inside one of my stubs, the value of the property `statusCode` of the response object is changed to `200`. However, at the end of the test, Mocha reports it as being the default value for the property (500, in this case).

Here is the test code:

```
it('should return status 200 if product was saved', function(){
    //fake objects
    const fakeReq = {
        flash(){return true},
        body:{
            title: '',
            price: 0,
            description: ''
        },
        file: {
            path: 'path'
        },
        session: {
            user: ''
        }
    }
    const fakeRes = {
        statusCode: 500,
        redirect(){
            this.statusCode = 200; //this successfully changes to 200
            return this;
        }
    }
    //fake methods
    sinon.stub(expressValidator, 'validationResult').callsFake(fakeValidation);
    sinon.stub(Product.prototype, 'save').callsFake(sinon.fake.resolves('ok'));

    //expectations
    adminController.postAddProduct(fakeReq, fakeRes, ()=>{});
    sinon.restore();
    expect(fakeRes.statusCode).to.equal(200); //test fails returning 500
});
```

Here is the method that I want to test, more specifically, the `product.save()` call, at the end:

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const validationErrors = validationResult(req);
  if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
    req.flash('validationErrors', validationErrors.array());
    return res.status(422).redirect('/admin/add-product');
  }
  const title = req.body.title;
  const image = req.file;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  if(!image){
    req.flash('validationErrors', [{param:'productImage', msg: 'Insira uma imagem válida!'}]);
    return res.status(422).redirect('/admin/add-product');
  }
  const product = new Product({
    title: title,
    price: price,
    imageUrl: image.path,
    description: description,
    userId: req.session.user
  });
  product.save()
    .then(results => {
      return res.redirect('/admin/products');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      next(new Error(err));
    });
};
```

**EDIT:**
Changed the test function to use a spy in order to check if the `redirect` method was being called, but it's always returning false. I'm thinking that it might be because Js doesn't pass by reference, unless the contents of the object gets changed. New testing code:

```
const fakeRes = {
        status(code){
            this.statusCode = code;
            return this;
        },
        redirect(){return true;},
        statusCode: 500
    }
    const redirectSpy = sinon.spy(fakeRes, 'redirect');

    //fake methods
    sinon.stub(expressValidator, 'validationResult').callsFake(fakeValidation);
    sinon.stub(Product.prototype, 'save').callsFake(sinon.fake.resolves('ok'));

    //expectations
    adminController.postAddProduct(fakeReq, fakeRes, ()=>{});
    sinon.restore();
    expect(redirectSpy.withArgs('/admin/products').calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just test that redirect is called? That's the responsibility of the function you're testing, and a redirect is 3xx anyway.

Comment: To test if the redirect has been called I should use Sinon Spy, right? I made the question because I got really confused about the value that Mocha was returning, more than the resolution itself. About the redirect code, It's my bad, I thought Express would default to 200 if not specified, but according to the docs, it defaults to 302.

Comment: Have you try `await adminController.postAddProduct` ?